# Fastest way to insert data(5000 rows) in dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have 5000 json data points which I am iterating and holding data in dataframe. 
 Initially I am adding data in series list and thereafter adding it into dataframe using below code

`1. (5000 times)pd.Series([trading_symbol, instrument_token], index=stock_instrument_token_df.columns)`

then:

`2. (once) stock_instrument_token_df.append(listOfSeries, ignore_index=True)`

time taken in executing 1 is around 700-800 ms and 2 is around 200-300ms
So overall it takes around 1 second for this process

Before this I am iterating through another set of 50,000 json data points and adding them into python dict. That takes around 300 ms

Is there any faster way to do insertion in data frame.
Is there something wrong the way I am looping through data or inserting in data frame ?
Is there any faster way to get work done in dataframe?

Complete code as requested, if it helps

```
stock_instrument_token_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first', 'second'])
            listOfSeries = []
            for data in api_response:
                trading_symbol = data[Constants.tradingsymbol]
                instrument_token = data[Constants.instrument_token]
                listOfSeries.append(
                    pd.Series([trading_symbol, instrument_token], index=stock_instrument_token_df.columns))
            stock_instrument_token_df = stock_instrument_token_df.append(listOfSeries, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You should add samples for replicating the question and a desired answer as well. Thanks

Comment: Try using the numpy library. It might accelerate what you're trying to do.

Comment: you should give your data as well because by considering dummy data I can't make any claim on performance improvement.

Comment: Adding 1 row from the data set, simply multiply it 5000 times and u have ur data for analysis . I hope it helps. I am trying to make a dataframe because I want to split data into subsets based on dates`{'date': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800)), 'open': 557.7, 'high': 572, 'low': 555.25, 'close': 569.65, 'volume': 3753262}`

Comment: It's always helpful to add is a complete set of date. I know the problem is familiar to you, but it isn't to anyone else, so I'm trying to solve your problem, but I cannot easily match up your one data point with the labels in your code. So now I have to try and figure it out, which is not what I really want to do, and probably why you are not getting answers to your question.

Comment: Your code is slowing down in two places. 1. You are iterating and appending, 2. you are creating pd.series for every data point. The solution is to try and join your data BEFORE you create the dataframe, and then put it in in one shot.